# POST http://localhost:8000/api/posts/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I can not get rid of this error:

POST http://localhost:8000/api/posts/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

I am using a react frontend with a django rest api backend. I am trying to upload multiple images at once from an input form. It worked before with slightly different code for one image. Any ideas maybe? Here is my code:

```
class App extends Component {

state = {
images: null
  };

handleImageChange = (e) => {
this.setState({
  images: e.target.files
})
};

handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log(this.state);
let form_data = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.images.length; i++) {
  form_data.append('image[]', this.state.images[i]);
}
let url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/posts/';
axios.post(url, form_data, {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
};

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <p>
        <input type="file"
               id="image"
               accept="image/png, image/jpeg" multiple  onChange={this.handleImageChange} required/>
      </p>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
);
  }
}
```

export default App;

```
class PostView(APIView):
parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    posts_serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.POST.getlist('image[]'))
    for onepost in posts_serializer:
        if onepost.is_valid():
            onepost.save()
            return Response(onepost.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            print('error', onepost.errors)
            return Response(onepost.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Since you're getting a 500 that means to me it is reaching your API endpoint. Can you add a print or log on the first line of your post function to see how the data is reaching your endpoint? That's where I would start

Comment: @MichaelHallabrin posts_serializer = 
PostSerializer(data=[<InMemoryUploadedFile: cocosign.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: mentimeter_qr_code.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: 1PSM Logo.png (image/png)>]):
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    image = ImageField(max_length=100)

Comment: if your `PostSerializer` object is a DRF serializer object, I dont think it is supposed to be iterable.

Comment: I attempted to find some documentation for the PostSerializer class and couldn't find anything except [this article about](https://simplecheatsheet.com/tag/django-rest-framework-cheat-sheet/) a custom class with the same name.